# Run windows batch file to call on python scripts with my anaconda environment

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda

I have anaconda installed and wanted to call on my python scripts through the Windows Batch File ('.bat' extension). However, when I run my batch file, it says that the windows command prompt doesn't recognize python. So then, I add "conda activate" onto the batch file and it completely messes up my anaconda environment installed on my laptop.

I understand that anaconda installs a separate environment for running python onto my laptop so should I just install the normal python.exe to run this batch file or can I find ways to activate my anaconda base onto command prompt?

Comment: You could call Python with its full path.

Answer (score 0):

Pop up an anaconda prompt
Type path
It will say something like

```
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;...
```

Copy from C:\ to C:\Windows\system32.  Paste it at point XXX in your batch file

The batch file

```
setlocal
path XXX;%path%
python script.py
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Booting application.."
conda init
conda activate YOUR_ENV
python script.py
read -p "Press [Enter] key to close window..."
```